# Train HMM in R with multiply sequences

Tags: r, machine-learning, hidden-markov-models, probability-density

I have a data.frame (40K lines) .

```
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      
[1,] "state 1" "state 3" NA        NA        NA        
[2,] "state 2" "state 4" "state 4" NA        NA        
[3,] "state 2" "state 4" "state 5" "state 3" "state 82"
```

Each line contains info about sequence of states. Number of states is fixed (~200). Length of sequence varies.

Is it possible to exec some function for finding multiply sequences with max probabilities:

```
get_rank_seq(df = myframe, states = levels(as.factor(c(myframe))) )
```

I don't want to apply that "model" to test data. Required to analyze only the original data set. I think that this problem is based on the Language Processing and HMM.

Thanks to all.